# OpenSSL 1.0.1t does not decrypt with -bf if encrypted with OpenSSL version 1.1.0e

Tags: openssl, blowfish

I have encrypted a file with the same command line with two different openssl versions: 1.0.1t and 1.1.0e. Then I try to decode both with version 1.0.1t and I cannot decode the latter.

Can you please tell me why and where am I wrong? How can I encrypt and safely decrypt without changing the command line: `openssl enc -d -a -bf -in <infile> -out <outfile> -pass pass:<password>`?

If you would like to answer on more question: how can I make the cipher more resilient?

Here's how to reproduce the situation. 
On the host with openssl 1.0.1t:

`user@101t$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
user@101t$ echo "pippo" > prova
user@101t$ openssl enc -e -a -salt -bf -in "prova" -out "prova1.enc" -pass pass:pippo`

On the host with openssl 1.1.0e:

`user@110e$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
user@110e$ echo "pippo" > prova
user@110e$ openssl enc -e -a -salt -bf -in "prova" -out "prova2.enc" -pass pass:pippo`

Copy prova1.enc to the host with openssl 1.0.1t and then into it type:

`user@101t$ openssl enc -d -a -bf -in prova1.enc -out x -pass pass:pippo
user@101t$ openssl enc -d -a -bf -in prova2.enc -out x -pass pass:pippo
bad decrypt
139637189576336:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:516:`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default digest used for generating the key from the password changed in OpenSSL 1.1.0. In versions prior to that md5 was used - which is now considered insecure. In OpenSSL 1.1.0 the default digest is sha256.

In order to decrypt a file in OpenSSL 1.0.1t generated by OpenSSL 1.1.0 you should add "-md sha256" to your command line arguments. If that is not possible then you can also force OpenSSL 1.1.0 to use md5 as its digest by adding "-md md5" to the encryption command line arguments. This is obviously insecure but should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a note: before posting the issue I have tried to change the digests config parameter in openssl.cnf to digests = md5, sha1 but it didn't solve the problem. Is it possible to set md5 as default without specifying it as a command line argument?

Comment: No, unfortunately that isn't possible. The "enc" application only reads the digest from the command line args and not from the config file. Please could you mark my answer as correct if it addresses your issue?

Comment: -1 for suggesting that SHA-256 is secure for this use.