# What changed in openssl enc file format between versions 1.0 and 1.1?

Tags: openssl

I have some files encrypted under OpenSSL 1.0 with `openssl aes-256-cbc -e`, with a password.

I can decrypt them with 1.0, but it produces gibberish under any later version.

Commands I can use to test this. This one still works:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/*/bin/openssl aes-256-cbc -d < encrypted-file
```

This one produces gibberish with the same password:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/*/bin/openssl aes-256-cbc -d < encrypted-file
```

What changed between these versions? Is there any way to pass some command line options to support older format? I can't find any documentation anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL 1.0.1t does not decrypt with -bf if encrypted with OpenSSL version 1.1.0e](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160183/openssl-1-0-1t-does-not-decrypt-with-bf-if-encrypted-with-openssl-version-1-1-0). Also documented in [openssl-enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html): *"The default digest was changed from MD5 to SHA256 in OpenSSL 1.1.0."*.

Comment: Turns out passing `-md md5` makes newer versions able to decode old files.